# Magento 1.8 Payment methods

Tags: payment-methods

We need to show the payment method based on stores. We have 4 type of payment methods(ICICI,HDFC, Paypal,Authorize.net ). 
Our client request to show payment based on stores (Store1,Store2). We also checked in admin panel, there is only set country based payment method.
We need show the payment method of stor1 is ICICI and HDFC.
And Stor2 is Paypal and Authorize.net.
How to  do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you log into the admin section and navigate to the payment methods part of the configuration you will see that most payment methods have a flag "Is Active".

You will also see that on the left hand side you can switch to different store levels for setting store specific configuration.

Sadly though most payment types only have the active flag allowing to change on a website level and not a store level.

You could try updating these payment methods so that they have the flag `<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>` and this should then allow you to update the active flag for each payment method on a store level.